# Set page title with Vue Router

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I have created a **vue-router** with a page title (h1).
Every vue-router link has a meta-title. How can I dynamically set my h1 page title?

I have tried `$emit`, but this is not working in my router. How can I change my page title?

```js
const dashboard = {
  template: `<div>DASHBOARD</div>`
}
const about = {
  template: `<div>ABOUT</div>`
}

const routes = [
  {path: '/dashboard', component: dashboard, name:'dashboard', meta: { title: 'Dashboard' }},
  {path: '/about', component: about, name:'about', meta: { title: 'About' }}
]
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for routes: routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  this.$emit('pagetitle', to.meta.title); // DOESN'T WORK!!
  next();
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  data() {
    return {
      pagetitle: 'not set'
    }
  },
  watch: {
    '$route': function(value) {
    // I can use things like value.name === 'about', but "watch" doesn't set the page title at the first page load.
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <router-link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</router-link>
  <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
  <router-view></router-view>
  <h1 v-text="pagetitle"></h1>
  How can I change the page title???
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your `<h1></h1>` tag, just use the following

```
{{ $route.meta.title }}
```

Comment: Sorry. It doesn't work. I get an error "$routes" is not defined"

Comment: @angelique000 Hi, it was a spelling mistake. It should be `$route` rather than `$routes`. Thank you for the comment and pointing it out.

Answer (score 15):

If you would like to have correct browser history use this one:

```
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  Vue.nextTick( () => {
    document.title = to.meta.title ? to.meta.title : 'default title';
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks, you comment helped a lot. Is there a reason you use `nextTick`?

Comment: `Vue.nextTick()` is a command that instructs Vue to wait until after the current DOM update, which means it waits until after the UI is painted before it paints it again. Think of a tick as an analogy for a moment in time. The UI is a recurrent render loop. The painting process is sychronous and deterministic, and it repeats over and over again. `Vue.nextTick()` says "wait until the next paint to ensure the current state has been resolved first."

Comment: You can also use `Vue.nextTick()` inside an async function with syntax such as: `async () => { await Vue.nextTick(); this.val = 'new'; }.` Note the difference between using it as a promise-returning sleep function and between using the first parameter as a callback function for "continuation passing style". You can stack them like inception, but try to keep it maximum one depth to avoid christmas tree, callback hell debugging problems.

Comment: @agm1984 you exlpained what nextTick does, but not why it's needed here.

Comment: Vue does not repaint anything beyond the HTML element it was mounted to. In the usual case it means nothng beyond `body.div#app` would be repainted. As the title is located in `head.title`, beyond body, it is not affected by Vue. Hence no need to use `nextTick()`.

Answer (score 1):

Also if you need to change the document's title-tag, in your `router.beforeEach` replace this line :

`this.$emit('pagetitle', to.meta.title);`

with

`document.title = to.meta.title;`

It will work.